# How to create session using SessionFactory in liferay finder classes

Tags: liferay

I have a custom sql and I wrote a finder class for it:

```
public class PopulationFinder
{   
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "public.population";
    public static String FINDBYNUM = "ir.nsdp.srp.ruraldevelopment.portlet.ac.persistence.PopulationFinderImpl.findByNum";

    public List<Population> findByNum(OrderByComparator obc, String lowerRangeEqual,
            int lowerRange, String upperRangeEqual, int upperRange, int start, int end) throws SystemException {

    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = openSession();

        String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FINDBYRUSTA);

        sql = StringUtil.replace(sql, "[$JOIN$]", getJoin(null));
        sql = StringUtil.replace(sql, "[$WHERE$]", getWhere(null));

        sql = CustomSQLUtil.replaceOrderBy(sql, obc);

        SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

        q.setCacheable(false);
        q.addEntity(TABLE_NAME, PopulationImpl.class);

        QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(q);
        qPos.add(lowerRangeEqual);
        qPos.add(lowerRange);
        qPos.add(upperRangeEqual);
        qPos.add(upperRange);

        if (!Validator.isNull(obc))
            qPos.add(obc);

            return (List<Population>) QueryUtil.list(q, getDialect(), start, end);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e);
        } finally {
            closeSession(session);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't have access to openSession method because I didn't extend BasePersistenceImpl.
In case I extend it, because I want to make my findByNum method to be static so I be able to call it from anywhere, it took error to openSession because I make a non-static reference.

I want to create session manually in this method. Is that possible?

Comment: How does extending a class affecting making a static method?

Comment: Because the class that I extended have non-static methods that I use in my static method and that is obviously not possible

Comment: this "being able to call the static method from everywhere" sounds like a weird architectural choice for me. Why would you want to call it from everywhere, rather than going through the proper channels?

Comment: No I mean I don't want to instantiate it, call it via class name,

Comment: It appears from your questions that this is not possible. Am I right ?

Comment: You pattern is wrong for creating custom finder classes. You can follow [***DEVELOPING CUSTOM SQL QUERIES***](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries) for reference.

Comment: Also, finder methods are available as static method from your entity `*LocalServiceUtil` class.